# Proceed to next empty cell if a condition is met

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a sheet with Item names in the firs row.

[image]

I am using a `For`loop to pass trough the cells in row 1 - `i`.
I use the value content of each cell to import a column from a .CSV file in the corresponding cell below it in row 2, by using `j` for that.
However, I have some .CSV files that are missing and I need to move on to the next cell in row 2, while moving on to the next cell in row 1. Basically skipping a column.

What I have so far is:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Betty\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\B4D9BCD10BE9B5248AFCB2BE2411BA10\MQL4\Files")

For i = 2 To HCP.Cells(1, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Item = HCP.Cells(1, i).Value

FilePath = Folder & "\" & Item & "1440.CSV"

    If Item = "" Or Dir(FilePath) = "" Then GoTo Continue
        j = HCP.Cells(2, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With HCP.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FilePath, Destination:=HCP.Cells(2, j + 1))
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

Continue:

Next
```

I need the column index of `j` to be corresponding to the column index of `i` at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 3: Nested `For`Loop with Nested `If`Statement

```
For i = 1 To BS.Cells(1, BS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 1 To BS.Cells(2, BS.Columns.Count - 1).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Item = BS.Cells(1, i).Value
        FilePath = Folder & "\" & Item & "1440.CSV"

            If ((Item <> "") Or (Dir(FilePath) <> "") And (i = j)) Then

                 With BS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FilePath, Destination:=BS.Cells(2, j + 1))
                     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                     .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                     .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                 End With

            End If

     Next j

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using `GoTo Continue`. Just check the negative of your statements before entering the loop. You are also missing some `End If` statement in both your question and solution.

I left comments showing where the code will skip to if either `Item` or `Dir` are blank. Same result, just cleaner code.

```
For i = 2 To HCP.Cells(1, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Item = HCP.Cells(1, i).Value
FilePath = Folder & "\" & Item & "1440.CSV"

    If Item <> "" Or Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then 'Test Here
        j = HCP.Cells(2, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If j <> i Then j = i
                With HCP.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FilePath, Destination:=HCP.Cells(2, j))
                    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                End With
    End If 'Skips to here if either are blank.
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you @urdearboy for both correcting my code and improving it. +1

Comment: However, I get a "Compile error: End If without a block If" on the second End If . @urdearboy

Comment: Updated @I.Я.Newb sorry about that

Comment: The condition should be `If Item <> "" And Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then 'Test Here`, with `And`, not `Or`.

Comment: @urdearboy, I am un-marking your suggestion(s) as Answer as the code you shared is not a solution to the problem. Also, both of the conditions **must** be false separately, as the value `i` can be `<> " "`, but the file `j` may not be existent. By setting a condition `i` being non existent or `j`  being non-existent I can skip to `Next`.   Also, try to run the above with the  `If`statement without the `End If`. Please find a couple of solutions, using nested `For` and `Do` Loops in my answer.

Comment: Feel free to accept one of your solutions as an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is what I am using now.

```
For i = 2 To HCP.Cells(1, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Item = HCP.Cells(1, i).Value
FilePath = Folder & "\" & Item & "1440.CSV"

    If Item = "" Or Dir(FilePath) = "" Then GoTo Continue
        j = HCP.Cells(2, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If j <> i Then j = i
                With HCP.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FilePath, Destination:=HCP.Cells(2, j))
                    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                End With

Continue:

Next
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

Please, feel free to make any other suggestions.

Comment: In the above example the `Continue` command can be replaced with `Next Iteration`, as the `Continue` command is a non-VBA one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2: Nested `Do` Loop

Avoiding the "Continue" command, as it is not a VBA command.

```
For i = 2 To BS.Cells(1, BS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column: Do

Item = BS.Cells(1, i).Value
FilePath = Folder & "\" & Item & "1440.CSV"

    If Item = "" Or Dir(FilePath) = "" Then Exit Do
        j = BS.Cells(2, BS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If j <> i Then j = i
                With BS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FilePath, Destination:=BS.Cells(2, j))
                    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                End With

Loop While False: Next i
```

Please, Notice the `: Do` at the end of the end of the `For i`.

If **one** of the following conditions, i.e. `Item = ""` or `Dir(FilePath) = ""` is `False` , then the `Do` loop is exited. True if the `Loop While False: Next i` condition for the `Do` loop is stated.

The two conditions may also be presented as:

```
For i = 2 To BS.Cells(1, BS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column: Do

If Item <> "" Or Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then

   'Do something...

Else: Exit Do

End If

Loop While True: Next i
```

Having the `Or` condition in the `If Item = "" Or Dir(FilePath) = "" Then Exit Do` is mandatory as `i` may be `Value <> " "`, but the `FilePath` to the file may be non-existent i.e. `Dir(FilePath) = " "`, which will spit out an error as the previous I had.

The `If j <> i Then j = i` in this case is mandatory, as the `For i` is stated as `=2 To`, meaning that the loop starts from column 2.

This can be avoided by stating the `For i` loop as `For i = 1 To`. However this was the initial loop to get the job done.

Further `j` can be stated as `j = BS.Cells(2, i)`, obtaining the value of `i` for a column index.

However, the `If j <> i Then j = i` statement is advisable for further assurance purposes.

In further search more solutions emerged.

See **Solution 3: Nested `For` Loop with Nested `If` Statement**